# Visual Studio 2010 crashes, when running a edited solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

When i open a solution(specific project) in VS2010 and start with or without debugging ,it works fine 
but 
once i edit or add lines of code and then start the program ,it crashes .

1- Other Solutions are working fine .

2- Sometime it works fine , forexample two days ago ,it was working fine but when i shutdown the computer and restarted it , problem started again.

3- I am using PDF Viewer of PDFtron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash is due to Memory Over Flow when program is going to start . caused by some UserControl that is added to your form .Here in this case it is PdfViewer Control.

**Solution :**
Copy all initialization of PdfViewer from Form Designer  and paste it in a method and call this method in FormLoad Event.

This will not use the memory while Initializing Component but later when form is loading ,